# blockinfile keeps adding the block

Tags: ansible

I'd like to add a block of text to my ElasticSearch configuration using blockinfile, but every time I run my playbook, the block gets added to the file -- even when it already exists.  This is a problem because ElasticSearch doesn't just take the last value, it chokes on startup saying "you have multiple entries for this value" (or something similar).

My play looks like this:

```
  - name: configure elasticsearch
    blockinfile:
      dest: /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
      marker: "## added by ansible configuration"
      block: |
        network.host: 0.0.0.0
        path.data: /var/lib
        path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
        path.repo: /home/chris/elastic-backups
      state: present
```

But after running my playbook a second time, my `elasticsearch.yml` file looks like:

```
## added by ansible configuration
network.host: 0.0.0.0
path.data: /var/lib
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
path.repo: /home/chris/elastic-backups
## added by ansible configuration
network.host: 0.0.0.0
path.data: /var/lib
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
path.repo: /home/chris/elastic-backups
## added by ansible configuration
```

Is there a way to only add the block if it does not exist yet?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should specify `{mark}` keyword in the `marker` parameter:

```
marker: "## {mark} added by ansible (configuration elasticsearch)"
```

This will cause Ansible to insert a line at the beginning and at the end of the block replacing `{mark}` accordingly with `BEGIN` and `END`:

```
## BEGIN added by ansible (configuration elasticsearch)
network.host: 0.0.0.0
path.data: /var/lib
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
path.repo: /home/chris/elastic-backups
## END added by ansible (configuration elasticsearch)
```

Otherwise Ansible has no clue, where the block starts and where it ends, so on every run it considers the block is not present and inserts a new one.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is correct and straightforward.

But also `marker` string should not contain line breaks like `\n`, otherwise, Ansible will keep adding the block. Sounds like a bug for me

Comment: Yes i had the same, while i was trying to add a new line before the marker. Ended up in using a replace task to add the new line before the blockinline marker line, if it is not there already. http://mrtango.planetcrazy.de/ansible-add-an-empty-line-before-a-blockinfile.html